# SignalR transmit to different views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, signalr

I spend a lot of time trying to find some example on how to get response data to a different view than the one you are sending from.

Here is my scenario:

I'm pressing a button in View A and than want to show alert in all clients in View B

Send and receive work fine in a single view (all the examples I found are made this way)

View A:

```
<button id ="test"> Some button </button>
```

```
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        var sender = $.connection.messagesHub;

        // this works fine but I need this function to be called in a different view
        //sender.client.updateMachinesDisplay = function (machineId) {
        //    alert(machineId);
        //};

        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

            console.log('connection started Main');

            $('#test').click(function () {
                sender.server.sendMachineIdToHub(@Model.MachineId);
            });
        }).fail(function (reason) {
            console.log("SignalR connection failed: " + reason);
        });
    });
</script>
```

View B (here I want to see alert message):

```
        sender.client.updateMachinesDisplay = function (machineId) {
            alert(machineId);
        };
```

Here is server side code:

```
    public class MessagesHub : Hub
{

    [HubMethodName("sendMachineIdToHub")]
    public void SendMachineIdToHub(int machineId)
    {
        Clients.All.updateMachinesDisplay(machineId);
    }
}
```

Maybe putting some code to _Layout might be a solution ? I tried making sender to be global but it didn't work ot maybe I did something wrong. I'll also try to read a little more in SignalR documentation.

Comment: Where is your client side code? On all of the views, or not? If you plan on using SignalR on every view, the client side code needs to be on every page. Does this help? And how does View C even come into play? You never even say what you are changing or how you're raising the event.

Comment: What isn't working exactly?

Comment: @MarkC. I edited my post. View C can be omitted for simplification since I guess that redirect in controller doesn't change much. Client side code must be on every page -> Does sender must be a global variable in layout for this to work ? Also what about connection ?  Well the return method is called on server but but not in view B client

Comment: As long as it's all wrapped within a function (like your code is) it should work fine. I would throw all of your SignalR code into the same function block and all in the same page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, it took me a second to find your issue. I threw all of the SignalR Code into a single JS file and brought it into the shared _Layout page.

Here's the full working code:

### Hub

```
[HubName("messageHub")]
public class MessageHub : Hub
{ 
    [HubMethodName("sendMachineIdToHub")]
    public void SendMachineIdToHub(int machineId)
    {
        Clients.All.updateMachinesDisplay(machineId);
    }
}
```

### _Layout

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.2.0.js"></script>
<script src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/signalR.messageHub.js"></script> <!-- this is my JS File -->
```

### signalR.messageHub.js

```
$(function () {
    var sender = $.connection.messageHub;

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

        console.log('connection started Main');

        $('#test').click(function () {
            sender.server.sendMachineIdToHub(88);
        });
    }).fail(function (reason) {
        console.log("SignalR connection failed: " + reason);
    });

    sender.client.updateMachinesDisplay = function (machineId) {
        alert(machineId);
    };

});
```

I think you were trying to use the hub connection on a page where it wasn't a global variable or wasn't in scope (from the looks of it). The same variable that you're assigning your hub connection to is going to be responsible for sending/receiving messages from the Hub, so it needs to be on every page. You'll also need a connection to the Hub for this very reason.

Comment: I was able to adapt it in my own project,thanks for information